# Два вопроса по поводу struct termios

Tags: linux, c, консоль

Вот код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>

static struct termios stored_settings;

void set_keypress(void)
{
    struct termios new_settings;

    tcgetattr(0,&stored_settings);

    new_settings = stored_settings;

    new_settings.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);
 //  new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;

    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&new_settings);
    return;
}

void reset_keypress(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&stored_settings);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    set_keypress();
   // char m[5];
    printf("Test: ");

        // putchar здесь вызывается для того, чтобы проверить 
  //  работоспособность
        gets(); 

    reset_keypress();
    return 0;
}
```

Не понял пару моментов.

1. В описании `tcgetattr` говорится:

> Почти в каждом случае программы должны использовать tcgetattr() для получения текущих установок устройства

Зачем мне получать какие-то значения каких-установок какого-то устройства, почему я сразу не могу запихнуть структуру с настройками в `tcsetattr()`?

2. Зачем в строке `new_settings.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);` в операции присваивания добавлять побитовое И(&)?  Почему тогда в строке `new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;` не используется побитовое И?

Comment: 1. Чтобы ваша программа не загрязняла своими настройками предыдущие установки. При выходе из программы надо восстановить их. Это правило хорошего тона не только для TERMIOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Зачем мне получать какие-то значения каких-установок

Как правило ("Почти в каждом случае") Вы не будете заново задавать **все** настройки, а только изменять **некоторые**. Поэтому, разработчики **рекомендуют** Вам действовать так:

1. Считываем текущие настройки
2. Изменяем то, что желаем
3. Обновлённые настройки устанавливаем в устройстве.

> Зачем в строке new_settings.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);

Именно по причине из пункта 1. Смысл этой операции

```
new_settings.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);
```

как раз и заключается в том. что взять **текущие** настройки, погасить в них биты, заданные маской *ICANON* и записать в качестве **олбновления**.

В операции

```
new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;
```

старое настройка нас не интересует, поэтому мы просто задаём новое значение.

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно:-)